# Desktop Microfone spec decent for small business presentation

Tags: audio, sound-system

I have an assus prime

[my motherboard](https://www.asus.com/br/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-A320M-K-BR/?gclid=CjwKCAjw7p6aBhBiEiwA83fGuvucAcq2_hqtUHRshHLpybUtR7g533-42NWFRIjiP_LJGrsU1RBXmRoCoF4QAvD_BwE)

I am using Ubuntu... I don't know if it matters.

I need to know a good microfone for small presentation. I bought the  cheapeast lapel microphone. I it seems I was under a strong rain the sound of my voice was barely audible before the strong noise... very unusable

Can someone recommend a hardware that do the job... some solution 7 out of 10 would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [$30 Fifine mic](https://a.co/d/8C4mP6C). I bought it a while back and it works great. I can stand 10ft away and still sound very clear.